# Weird ar linking error

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, g++, unix-ar

1. Make the project from scratch (works)
2. Try to remake without changing any files (doesnt work)
3. Remove static library
4. Make again without changing any files (works)
5. Make again without changing any files (doesnt work)

Step 1 is of the form:

```
User@MacBook-Pro:~/$ make
g++  -o Install.o -c -m32 -g  Install.cpp
(same as prev command for all files, abbreviated for conciseness)
```

Here is the output of steps 2, 3, and 4

```
User@MacBook-Pro:~/$ make
ar rcs ./libRain.a DirectoryMonitor.o Install.o Machines.o Notifications.o RainDirectory.o ResourceShare.o Resources.o RowTransferProtocol.o Server.o Tags.o Transaction.o Triggers.o Util/ArrayList.o Util/ArrayList64.o Util/Buffer.o Util/CPU.o Util/CircularBuffer.o Util/Connection.o Util/DateTime.o Util/Directory.o Util/DownloadManager.o Util/EventHandler.o Util/ExtendibleHashTable.o Util/FILE_buffer.o Util/File.o Util/HttpRequest.o Util/HttpResponse.o Util/Http_Headers.o Util/Http_Message.o Util/Http_client.o Util/Iterator.o Util/JSON.o Util/Log.o Util/MD5.o Util/NetworkDevice.o Util/PosixThreads.o Util/ProgressChecker.o Util/RSA.o Util/Random.o Util/Registry.o Util/SHA1.o Util/SHA2_256.o Util/SSL_Connection.o Util/Security_General.o Util/Sql.o Util/SqlLite.o Util/StaticHashTable.o Util/SymmetricKey.o Util/System.o Util/TCP_Connection.o Util/TCP_Server.o Util/Threading.o Util/Timer.o Util/URL.o Util/UUID.o Util/Utils.o Util/Volumes.o Util/WindowsNetworkDevice.o Util/WindowsThreads.o Util/X509.o Util/X509Request.o Util/linked_list.o Util/network_objects.o Util/regex.o Util/sqlite3.o Util/str.o Util/test.o Util/utf8.o Util/wchar_t.o Util/xml.o delta.o git.o
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ./libRain.a(Machines.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ./libRain.a(Triggers.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ./libRain.a(Registry.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ./libRain.a(Utils.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ./libRain.a(Volumes.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ./libRain.a(WindowsNetworkDevice.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ./libRain.a(WindowsThreads.o) has no symbols
g++  -m32 -g  -L. -o ./Rain Rain.cpp -lRain -lgit2 -liconv -lpthread -lpcap -lm -lssl -lcrypto -lodbc -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreServices
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Install.o) object file './libRain.a(Install.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Notifications.o) object file './libRain.a(Notifications.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(RainDirectory.o) object file './libRain.a(RainDirectory.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(ResourceShare.o) object file './libRain.a(ResourceShare.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Resources.o) object file './libRain.a(Resources.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Server.o) object file './libRain.a(Server.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Tags.o) object file './libRain.a(Tags.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Transaction.o) object file './libRain.a(Transaction.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(ArrayList.o) object file './libRain.a(ArrayList.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Buffer.o) object file './libRain.a(Buffer.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Connection.o) object file './libRain.a(Connection.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(DateTime.o) object file './libRain.a(DateTime.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Directory.o) object file './libRain.a(Directory.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(EventHandler.o) object file './libRain.a(EventHandler.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(File.o) object file './libRain.a(File.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(HttpRequest.o) object file './libRain.a(HttpRequest.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(HttpResponse.o) object file './libRain.a(HttpResponse.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Http_Headers.o) object file './libRain.a(Http_Headers.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Http_Message.o) object file './libRain.a(Http_Message.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Http_client.o) object file './libRain.a(Http_client.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Iterator.o) object file './libRain.a(Iterator.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(NetworkDevice.o) object file './libRain.a(NetworkDevice.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(PosixThreads.o) object file './libRain.a(PosixThreads.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(RSA.o) object file './libRain.a(RSA.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Random.o) object file './libRain.a(Random.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(SHA1.o) object file './libRain.a(SHA1.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Sql.o) object file './libRain.a(Sql.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(SqlLite.o) object file './libRain.a(SqlLite.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(TCP_Server.o) object file './libRain.a(TCP_Server.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Threading.o) object file './libRain.a(Threading.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(Timer.o) object file './libRain.a(Timer.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(URL.o) object file './libRain.a(URL.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(UUID.o) object file './libRain.a(UUID.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(linked_list.o) object file './libRain.a(linked_list.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(regex.o) object file './libRain.a(regex.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(sqlite3.o) object file './libRain.a(sqlite3.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(str.o) object file './libRain.a(str.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(utf8.o) object file './libRain.a(utf8.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(wchar_t.o) object file './libRain.a(wchar_t.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(delta.o) object file './libRain.a(delta.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
warning: (i386) ./libRain.a(git.o) object file './libRain.a(git.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.

User@MacBook-Pro:~/$ rm libRain.a

User@MacBook-Pro:~/$ make
ar rcs ./libRain.a DirectoryMonitor.o Install.o Machines.o Notifications.o RainDirectory.o ResourceShare.o Resources.o RowTransferProtocol.o Server.o Tags.o Transaction.o Triggers.o Util/ArrayList.o Util/ArrayList64.o Util/Buffer.o Util/CPU.o Util/CircularBuffer.o Util/Connection.o Util/DateTime.o Util/Directory.o Util/DownloadManager.o Util/EventHandler.o Util/ExtendibleHashTable.o Util/FILE_buffer.o Util/File.o Util/HttpRequest.o Util/HttpResponse.o Util/Http_Headers.o Util/Http_Message.o Util/Http_client.o Util/Iterator.o Util/JSON.o Util/Log.o Util/MD5.o Util/NetworkDevice.o Util/PosixThreads.o Util/ProgressChecker.o Util/RSA.o Util/Random.o Util/Registry.o Util/SHA1.o Util/SHA2_256.o Util/SSL_Connection.o Util/Security_General.o Util/Sql.o Util/SqlLite.o Util/StaticHashTable.o Util/SymmetricKey.o Util/System.o Util/TCP_Connection.o Util/TCP_Server.o Util/Threading.o Util/Timer.o Util/URL.o Util/UUID.o Util/Utils.o Util/Volumes.o Util/WindowsNetworkDevice.o Util/WindowsThreads.o Util/X509.o Util/X509Request.o Util/linked_list.o Util/network_objects.o Util/regex.o Util/sqlite3.o Util/str.o Util/test.o Util/utf8.o Util/wchar_t.o Util/xml.o delta.o git.o
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ./libRain.a(Machines.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ./libRain.a(Triggers.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ./libRain.a(Registry.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ./libRain.a(Utils.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ./libRain.a(Volumes.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ./libRain.a(WindowsNetworkDevice.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ./libRain.a(WindowsThreads.o) has no symbols
g++  -m32 -g  -L. -o ./Rain Rain.cpp -lRain -lgit2 -liconv -lpthread -lpcap -lm -lssl -lcrypto -lodbc -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreServices
```

Comment: Was the files in libRain.a compiled with debug info (the "no symbols" warning) and in 32 bit mode (the architecture warning)? How do the compiler command line look for the library files?

Comment: Did you do step 1 in the same session?

Comment: @Beta yea i did them all in a row

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I added the compile command that I use for the individually files. I dont understand why this would change anything though since the library works the first time it is linked.

Comment: Hang on... steps 1 and 2 should have identical commands, but 1 is a bare command to build a single object file, and 2 is a call to Make which tries to build an archive. I don't think you're doing what you think you're doing.

Comment: @Beta that was just a shorthand (i updated the question to show more accurately what is happening (still with a small abbreviation))